# No encuentra ServiceWorker

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, pwa, service-workers

Tengo un proyecto con Laravel, Vuejs y quiero que sea PWA, ya tengo el service-worker, el manifest.json e hice el cambio a package.json, 
Pero tengo una duda, por ahora esta localhost:8000 y me dice

```
ServiceWorker registration failed:  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

¿Por qué pasa esto?, Qué necesito para que me reconozca el service-worker y así ser un PWA.

Comment: ¿cómo llamas al service worker y qué ruta y nombre tiene dicho archivo?

Comment: '/service-worker.js' y esta en la raíz del proyecto

Comment: ¿cuál es la raíz del proyecto? yo he implementado varios PWA con Laravel sin problema, pero necesito más detalles, más código.

Comment: Puedo preguntar ¿cómo lo has hecho?, Yo tengo problema con el service worker, ya tengo el manifest.json y eso si lo toma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es el código que utilizo para registrar los service worker, lo he usado con Laravel sin problema:

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
  console.log('Service worker already registered.')
} else {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', {
    scope: './'
  }).then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered for scope:'+ reg.scope);
  });
}
```

Dicho código lo tengo en una vista parcial que es cargada en todas las páginas, básicamente, y el archivo service-worker.js está en la carpeta public.

Comment: Influye que se este viendo en localhost:8000 o eso no tiene ningún problema

Comment: ¿Qué código hay dentro de service-worker.js?

Comment: En service-worker.js está el código necesario para crear el caché para cuando el usuario esté offline y su administración, en otras palabras, están los listeners de los eventos: install, fetch y refreshOffline.

Comment: Debería funcionar con localhost, sin embargo siempre lo he probado con HTTPS. Si deseas un poco más de información detallada, revisa: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/